# Java: Checking For Errors Without Compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Some large Java projects can take a long time to compile.  For example, 20 minutes or more.   Obviously, on a project of that size you don't want a build failing 18 minutes into it for a missing semicolon.

Will utilities like findbugs or other tools catch compilation errors for you without having to invest the time in compiling?

Thanks in advance either way

Steve

Comment: You can use an IDE

Comment: I think somewhere out there is an incremental compiler. Ask google for one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use an IDE.  This will show you errors in lines as you type them and even offer auto-fixes for them.  They also support incremental compilation so only the files effected by a change need to be re-compiled.

AFAIK Most IDEs support ant and maven builds.

Comment: Some popular Java IDEs are Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/), IntelliJ IDEA (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and NetBeans (http://netbeans.org/).

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence.  Do ANT & Maven have the capacity for incremental builds or checking for errors before doing the work of compiling?

Comment: @Steve They don't have incremental builds but IDEs which support them can do.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an IDE like `Eclipse`. This compiles/checks syntax on the fly while you type. The production that needs 20 min in oyur case, still stays the same (e.g Ant or MAven build)